# Passing a stack object in OOP

Tags: c++, oop, stack, header-files

I have been trying to create a maze program in C++ using a stack (the standard method I believe), but I just can't figure out how to pass the stack object by reference to other functions in the program. The declaration of the function in the header file has everything that I can see it needs, but I keep getting an error message when I try to run the program. This is the declaration of the function, and the utilization of the function in the implementation file:

Implementation:

```
void Maze::backTrack(int & rows, int & cols, stack <int> &maze)
```

Header:

```
void backTrack(int & rows, int & cols, stack <int> & maze);
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'stack'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: seems you are declaring something wrong but not sure what language you're using so cant offer any help, can you update your post to include specific language tag not just OOP (not even sure that tag applies to this questions)

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a namespace name `std::stack` and include it or forward declare it. So it should be:

```
void Maze::backTrack(int & rows, int & cols, std::stack<int> &maze)
```

Comment: @CluelessStan if my answer is solving your problem please mark it as a good answer and maybe  gimme a point;) Also consider if passing int& by reference is needed. If you do not modify it then passing small object by value is often faster and always not slower than by reference.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize I could do those things. It wont let me up-vote  your post until I have at least 15 reputation, but I did mark your answer as good. I wish I could do more. Thanks again!